# Passing data from a fragment to a custom adapter (for use with ListView)

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, adapter

I'm trying to send data retrieved from a bundle within a fragment into a ListView's adapter so that the data can be displayed, depending on previous user choices.

I can log that the correct data is being sent to my fragment, however when I try to pass that data into the constructor of my adapter the ListView doesn't get populated. I'm not sure if this is the correct way of going about getting the data to the adapter, especially since the data isn't coming from a cursor.

In my fragment, this is the relevant code:

```
public class AddEditRecipeActivityFragment extends Fragment {
ListView mListView;
private IngredientListAdapter mIngredientListAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: starts");
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_edit_recipe, container, false);


    mNameTextView = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.addedit_name);
    mAddItem = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.addGrocery);
    mDescriptionTextView = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.addedit_description);
    mMealType = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.addedit_meal);
    mSaveButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.addedit_save);

    mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lstIngredient);


    Bundle arguments = getArguments();

    String addedGrocery = arguments.getString("GroceryName");

    String addedGroceryGrams = arguments.getString("grams");

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: retrieved ingredient = " + addedGrocery
            + " retrieved amount = " + addedGroceryGrams );

   mIngredientListAdapter = new IngredientListAdapter(getActivity(), null,
            0, addedGrocery, addedGroceryGrams ) ;
    mListView.setAdapter(mIngredientListAdapter);


.... }
```

This is my Adapter code, modified from the CursorAdapter class:

```
public class IngredientListAdapter  extends CursorAdapter {
private static final String TAG = "IngredientListAdapter";

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Context mContext;
private String mIngredient;
private String mGrams;

public IngredientListAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags, String ingredient, String grams) {
    super(context, c, flags);
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.mIngredient = ingredient;
    this.mGrams = grams;
}

public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.ingrediend_listview, parent, false);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.ingredient = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ingredient);
    holder.amount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.amount);
    view.setTag(holder);

    return view;
}


public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    Log.d(TAG, "bindView: Starts");

    Log.d(TAG, "bindView: ingredient = " + mIngredient);

    holder.ingredient.setText(mIngredient);
    holder.amount.setText(mGrams);


}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView ingredient;
    TextView amount;
 }
}
```

When I try to view the logs for my IngredientListAdapter class, nothing shows up at all. Which is strange because I have another adapter extending CursorAdapter and those logs are working - perhaps because they involve the cursor parameter?

I'm clearly missing something important here, any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem, as mentioned in the other answer, is that your `Cursor` parameter is `null`, this tells the `CursorAdapter` that you don't want to have anything at all in your `ListView`, therefore nothing shows up.

Since you are not actually using a `Cursor`, extending `CursorAdapter` is not a good choice. Extending `ArrayAdapter` would be more appropriate.

Your adapter might look like this:

```
public class IngredientAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Ingredient> {
    public IngredientAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Ingredient> ingredients) {
       super(context, 0, ingredients);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       // Get the data item for this position
       Ingredient ingredient = getItem(position);    
       // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
       if (convertView == null) {
          convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_ingredient, parent, false);
       }
       // Lookup view for data population
       TextView ingredientName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ingredientName);
       TextView ingredientAmt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ingredientAmt);
       // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
       ingredientName.setText(ingredient.name);
       ingredientAmt.setText(ingredient.amt);
       // Return the completed view to render on screen
       return convertView;
   }
}
```

`Ingredient` would be a class you create to hold the information for each ingredient. You could add a `ViewHolder` to the adapter also, but it's not required.

Rather than passing the `addedGrocery` and `addedGroceryGrams` values directly into the constructor the way you have, which would only ever allow you to have one item in your `ListView`, or multiple items with the same value, you should pass in an `ArrayList` of `Ingredient` objects containing the information:

```
mIngredientListAdapter = new IngredientAdapter(getActivity(), ingredients);
mListView.setAdapter(mIngredientListAdapter);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It's working now, except the added ingredients and their amount aren't being saved to the List if I go to add another ingredient. I need to somehow save the state of the ArrayList, although I'm not sure how to implement that in code... Any advice? :)

Comment: Nevermind. Simply needed to make the List static, so only one instance exists.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to make a new answer here but the comment line too short to expand my viewpoint.

The first let image that your adapter should have 2 things to manage. The first thing's the view of each list view's item. You have done it by adding the view holder. The second thing's the data of the view. Because you using the Cursor adapter so you don't need to prepare the `List<E>` inside of this adapter. The cursor did it for you. However, you forgot to prepare it by passing null into constructer.

Please read [this article](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter) slowly. That's good for you.

Your problem here:

```
public class AddEditRecipeActivityFragment extends Fragment {
...

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
    // The cursor's null
    mIngredientListAdapter = new IngredientListAdapter(getActivity(), null, 0, addedGrocery, addedGroceryGrams ) ;
    mListView.setAdapter(mIngredientListAdapter);
...
}
```

And here:

```
public class IngredientListAdapter  extends CursorAdapter {
...
public IngredientListAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags, String ingredient, String grams) {
    super(context, c, flags);  // c null now
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.mIngredient = ingredient;
    this.mGrams = grams;
}
...
```

Hope this help.